# Save merged contacts information

Tags: contacts, backup

I just spent a lot of time merging contacts from different sources (two Google accounts, Google+, Twitter, Facebook, Skype), and now my contact list looks somewhat clean for the first time in months. So far so good.

In the past, when I reset my phone (I'm a CyanogenMod user, so resetting my phone happens from time to time), I lost all info about merged contacts, which is really a pain. Is it possible to back up and restore this information somewhere, e.g. through an app?

edit: I did the merging in the stock contact manager of Ice Cream Sandwich (CM 9 alpha)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your contacts should all be backed up to the Google account you registered your phone with, provided that you are saving your contacts to Google and not your SIM card.  Check to make sure that you are using Google as your default contact list, and that syncing for contacts for that account is checked.

UPDATE: 
You can use [Titanium Backup](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en) to migrate settings between ROM wipes for other apps/contacts.

Comment: The contacts are synced, that isn't the problem. What doesn't seem to get synced to Google is the information on joined contacts from other providers (Skype, facebook, ...). That information is lost after a reset AFAICT

Answer (score 3):

Although just a "little" late I did create a free application called Total Backup to save and restore most of the contact joins without needing root. It can be found at [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.softwareshack.totalbackup) or [Amazon Appstore](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HYR9K30). Don't hesitate with feedback.